# Running a Perl script on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: perl

I am running the following perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

if ( @ARGV != 2 ){
print "usage: /usr/local/bin/htpasswd.pl <username> <password>\n";
}
else {
print $ARGV[0].":".crypt($ARGV[1],$ARGV[1])."\n";
}
```

but getting the error

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

I'am not getting why.
So can anybody tell me why am geting this error?
Guys sorry i forgot to tell
I am using this script to create htpasswd file using following command

```
/usr/local/bin/htpasswd.pl <user> <password> >> /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
```

Comment: "I am running the following perl script" — How?

Comment: If **bash** is complaining that `<` is unexpected token, how is it involved in this? There's no sign of any bash in your question (unless `/usr/bin/perl` is the path of a strangely named bash binary instead of perl)

Comment: if everything else fails, try to copy & paste your script to a new file... you may have a hidden corrupted character somewhere...

Comment: That is what am not getting why it is showing bash

Comment: guys sorry i forgot to tell that am using this script to create a htpasswd file using below command                                                                       /usr/local/bin/htpasswd.pl <user> <password> >> /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users

Comment: syntax of your program is correct. you may have some problem with your input data.

Comment: `-bash:` indicates the program is being run by `bash`, not `perl`!!!

Answer (score 2):

> i forgot to tell that am using this script to create a htpasswd file using below command `/usr/local/bin/htpasswd.pl <user> <password> >> /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users`

You have to replace `<user>` and `<password>` with the username and password you want to pass as arguments.

e.g.

```
/usr/local/bin/htpasswd.pl bob 'TjV7!cdbta1AGs' >> /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
```

`<` and `>` have special meaning on the command line, but in the instructions they are just indicating placeholders.

The error message you are getting is because you have a second `<` at the point where it is expecting the name of the file to use a STDIN.

Comment: even though replacing username & password am getting the same error

Comment: @ChetanPatil — I only get the error when I don't replace `<username>` and `<password>`. Did you replace the whole placeholder or did you leave the angle brackets in place? You have to replace the whole placeholder.

Comment: Got it Thank you Quentin i was doing mistake by using <> your solution worked

Answer (score -1):

the problem is in the `<user>`  `<password>`. Use proper input

example

```
/usr/local/bin/htpasswd.pl test 'pass' >> /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
```

Comment: `>>` is fine, changing it will cause it to overwrite the file instead of appending to it. The error message is about `<` not `>`.

Comment: I don't see how a permission issue would cause an unexpected token error.